# mod_rewrite: do not apply here

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite to put a category name in the URL, like locahost/categoryName and also a location localhost/categoryName/locationName .

One question I had, and I'm sure it's easy to do as a rewrite rule, is how can I make it so that the rule does not apply to some specific directory, like: localhost/admin . In that case I want it to go to the actual physical directory.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe better on serverfault.com?

Comment: questions on mod-rewrite seems to be accepted here.

Comment: Did not know about serverfault.com. Should I go there next time for mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make this your first rule:

```
RewriteRule localhost/admin - [L]
```

That means: match `localhost/admin`, do nothing, last rule (only if matched).

Comment: will it match /admin/something? /admin? /admin/ ? etc ...?

Comment: Yeah.  It will match `/administrator`, for that matter.  Put a slash on the end to only match `/admin` and things under it.